# Scion of the Ur-Dragon and Grave Pact

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I use [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon)'s ability and put a dragon card from my library into the grave yard, does that trigger [Grave Pact](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grave%20Pact)?

Answer (score 4):

No, Scion puts a dragon card directly from the library into the graveyard. Grave Pact triggers on things moving from the battlefield to a graveyard.

Note the Oracle text on the card has been updated to say 'Whenever a creature you control dies' instead of 'Whenever a creature you control in put into a graveyard from the battlefield', though they mean the same thing:

> **700.4.** The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”

Comment: It might help to point out that all actual printings of Grave Pact use the "whenever a creature you control is put into a graveyard from the battlefield" wording, and that that's equivalent to the eratta'd wording.

Comment: Also worth noting that even without "dies" / "from the battlefield", a creature card in your library is not "a creature you control."

Comment: @Gendolkari I considered adding that too but didn't feel it was necessary